# Multiple buttons with same class don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created multiple buttons with the same class from a list of words.

```
var words = $(this).val().split(' ');
    $.each(words, function(i, v) {
         if ($.trim(v) !== '') {
            html += "<button class='wordbtn'>"+ v +"</button>" + " "
         }
    });

$("p").html(html);
```

The buttons are displayed in my view, but when I click the button does not work.

```
$(".wordbtn").click(function(){
    console.log('clicked')
})
```

When I inspect my code buttons are shown, but when I view the source code the buttons are not displayed. 
If I insert a pre button to test, it works.

```
<p><button class='wordbtn'>Test</button><p>
```

Comment: that's because javascript is executed on the clients side, after the source code is loaded. Attach the event directly after `$("p").html(html);` maybe?

Comment: JS code will never affect "View Source".

Comment: If these buttons are created dynamically AFTER the .click handler is added, then of course those buttons wont have a click handler added, javascript obeys the laws of space time. you need to add the click event after creating the buttons, or use event delegation technique when adding the click event handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think the problem is that the *wordbtn* buttons still doesn't exists when you are running the code

```
$(".wordbtn").click(function(){
    console.log('clicked')
})
```

so the click event is not assigned to any element in your page.

try replace the click event for your button with:

```
$(document).on("click", ".wordbtn", function(event){
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

now the click event will fired even with a new added button, this because the event is handled by the a present document element after it bubbles to there.

Comment: you should explain how this approach is different from what he is trying.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are running this code:

```
$(".wordbtn").click(function(){
    console.log('clicked')
})
```

*before* you are creating the buttons.

This can't work, because those buttons don't exist and, thus, you can't add an event to them.

Using something called 'event delegation' you can get the effect you want.

https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 0):

All events won't listen to generated elements after the event listener added. See below examples with **JQuery** and pure **JavaScript**

Try Pure Javascript `e.target` with `docuemnt.event`

```js
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var words = this.value.replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim().split(" ");
  var html = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    html += "<button class='wordbtn'>" + words[i] + "</button>" + " ";
  }

  document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = html;
});
// add click event to DOM
window.onclick = function(e) {
  //detect if mouse clicked on element has class "wordbtn"
  if (e.target.className.indexOf("wordbtn") > -1) {
    console.log('clicked')
  }

}
```

```html
<input id='input' />
<p id='p'></p>
```

JQuery `$(document).on(event,target,callbak);`

```js
var str = "some words from user inputs";

$("#input").keyup(function() {
  var words = $.trim($(this).val().replace(/\s+/g, " ")).split(' ');
  var html = "";
  $.each(words, function(i, v) {
    html += "<button class='wordbtn'>" + v + "</button>" + " "
  });

  $("p").html(html);

});

$(document).on("click", ".wordbtn", function() {
  console.log('clicked')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='input' />
<p></p>
```